# Application settings equivalent for Avalonia

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui, avalonia

I was checking out Avalonia for porting over a WPF project, but I saw under the project settings there is no tab for application settings, only for resources.

In the WPF version of the app, I use `Settings.Default.Save()` and `Settings.Default.Reset()` to work with my saved settings during runtime. Manually copying my settings file over to my Avalonia version lets me access them with `Settings.Default.[field name]`, but I can no longer save or reset them.

I was wondering if Avalonia had an option for settings, but I haven't found one in the documentation. Is there an option for this, or should I save them manually to a file: and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Installing the NuGet package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager did the trick in resolving the error. I didn't realize I needed to install this since it was included with the default WPF project.