# How to load and save settings in Avalonia like WPF Settings.Default?

Tags: avalonia

The Properties.Ressources in Avalonia looks nearly the Settings Designer, but something isn't as I expected. The main issue is I cannot Save anything back...thats much annoing and not helpful at all. Reading a lot here and on the google universe, but cannot find anything suitable in the first sight.

Here is a related question in stackoverflow:
[Application settings equivalent for Avalonia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857944)
but it´s older and the Nuget Package says: "use something newer"

> Provides types that support using XML configuration files (app.config). This package exists only to support migrating existing .NET Framework code that already uses System.Configuration. When writing new code, use another configuration system instead, such as Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.

Other posts said, right click and add Settings and use it the old way, but this getting worse and failed in Avalonia...

Is that the way:  ?
[KeyPerFileConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#key-per-file-configuration-provider)

I need only simple Key/Value pairs like the old
Properties.Settings.Default.xxxxxxxx = yyyyy;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

I used these old way since years in all my projects and this is fire and forget.
Sure, I can save and read a .txt file or something else manually...but I wont this.

Answer (score 0):

Application settings aren't strictly UI so Avalonia doesn't support them.  You can use whatever method you like.  XML, JSON, YAML, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, you name it.  It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks Tarazed and a Happy new Year!  I going deeper into JSON and it works. Wrote an answer to my Post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, seems very simply, I'm following now is:
(Get it from these page: [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json)

Install 2 Nuget Packages

1. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

edit the .csproj as describes and put a json file into the project, in my example with my pairs Key/Value

"Settings": {
"autoOpen": "true",
"lastActiveDevice": "161",
"lastBaudRate": "9600",
"lastOpenPort":  "COM4"
}

a private variable to hold the settings

```
private IConfigurationSection pair;
```

In the MainView Constructor

```
    // Build a configuration object from JSON file
    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    // Get a configuration section
     pair = config.GetSection("Settings");

      // check the Output
    Debug.WriteLine($"lastActiveDevice: {pair["lastActiveDevice"]}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"autoOpen: {pair["autoOpen"]}");
```

Next step is to check how to write back values.

Comment: I'm very surprised, these config  can't save too! Is this an unnormal feature nowaddays? I found another question about that, even without any useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247847/how-the-configuration-can-be-saved-from-the-application   I dont wanna build a DB. So maybe I have to write an own read  write  JSON file method and hopefully thats it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).